# Conditioning on negligible event for continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Conditioning on a negligible event is often done for an absolutely continuous random variables, say $X$. It is not uncommon to encounter expressions such as $\mathbb{P}(a<Y<b|X=x)$ for some other random variable $Y$ (assume it absolutely continuous too for simplicity). This expression can be made sense of as a limit: $\lim_{\epsilon\longrightarrow 0}\mathbb{P}(a<Y<b|x-\epsilon\leq X\leq x+\epsilon)$.

The computation of this limit goes through expressing the numerator and denominator defining the conditional probability as integral of the joint density of $X,Y$ over the set $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]\times[a,b]$ and of the density of $X$ over $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ respectively.

My questions are: why would this limit always exist (in $[0,1]$ that is)? Given that it does, would it be the same as that obtained by replacing $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$ with $[x,x+\epsilon]$ for example? Cheers.

Comment: Usually such an expression is used when integrating over x.

Comment: seen it plenty of times on its own in many published papers

Comment: In those cases the author needs  to define it.

Comment: it is on wikipedia too though, I think it is pretty standard

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditioning_(probability)

Comment: precisely in the section about conditioning on the level of densities, subsection 'interpretation'.

Comment: by the way, I also dislike this informal way of proceeding, it is often the case that there are alternative ways to use a more appropriate probabilistic formalism, but it is striking that it is a heuristics that pretty much works, so I am interested in seeing if there is some consistency to it, as in many areas it is an accepted formalism in proofs that requires no explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of the limit through Radon–Nikodym theorem and Lebesgue's differentiation theorem.

Fix a borel set  $A$ and define the following measure on $\mathbb{R}$.
$$\mu_{A}(C)=P(Y\in A \; , X \in C)$$

By absolutely continuity of $X$ we know that $\mu_{A}<<\mathcal{L}$ where $\mathcal{L}$  is the Lebesgue measure.
Now we apply Radon–Nikodym to find a measurable function $f$ so that for every Borel set $C$ we have
$$ \mu_{A}(C)=\int\limits_{C}{f dt} $$

We now apply Lebesgue differentiation theorem to get that for almost every $x$ we have
$$\lim\limits_{|B|\to 0}\frac{\int\limits_{B}{fdt}}{|B|}=\lim\limits_{|B|\to 0}\frac{P(Y\in A\; , X \in B)}{|B|}=f(x)$$
Where the limit is taken over balls $B$ centerd at $x$ and $|B|$ is their length.

We have
$$\frac{P(Y \in A \; , X \in B)}{P(X \in B)}=\frac{|B|}{P(X \in B)}\frac{P(Y \in A \; , X \in B)}{|B|}$$
Then
$$\lim\limits_{|B|\to 0}\frac{P(Y \in A \; , X \in B)}{P(X \in B)}=\frac{f(x)}{f_{X}(x)}$$

This is the conditional expectation of the event $Y \in A$ given $X\;$(Defined as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) ). To see this note that for any event $X^{-1}(C) \in \sigma(X)$ we have $$\int\limits_{X^{-1}(C)}{\frac{f(X)}{f_{X}(X)}dP}=E(\chi_{C}(X)\frac{f(X)}{f_{X}(X)})=\int\limits_{C}{\frac{f(x)}{f_{X}(x)}f_{X}(x)dx}=P(Y \in A \; X \in C)=\int\limits_{X^{-1}(C)}{\chi_{A}(Y)dP}$$

This might not mean much if you've never read or done a course on measure theory but this is the 'formal' approach.

[Radon-Nikodym](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem)
[Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)

Comment: Would then the limit still exist if the balls are replaced by half balls? Would it be the same?

Comment: From the argument in the Lebesgue differentiation theorem it seems as though whatever set limiting to $x$ we consider, it has to contain a sufficiently rescaled ball around $x$. That is the limiting sets cannot have $x$ as a boundary point. But I do not see whether such a generalisation might hold.

Comment: The theorem still holds for half balls in this case. The sufficient condition is that diameter of the sets in the family must tend to 0 and that there is a constant $c$ so that for every element $S$ of the family, $\mathcal{L}(Q)\leq c\mathcal{L}(S)$ where $Q$ is the smallest cube centered at $x$ containing $S$. In this case we can take $c=2$.

Comment: See [Wheeden, R. L. (2015). Measure and integral: an introduction to real analysis (Vol. 308). CRC press.] Theorem 7.16 for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is of great help to make so many arguments I have read rigorous.

Comment: I actually have one last doubt: the denominator does not seem to be the one we would expect, since $|B|$ is different from $\mathbb{P}(X\in B)$ (unless $X$ has a suitable distribution), whereas I think that is usually the interpretation given to the limit, by definition of conditional probability. Does this mean that the heuristic interpretation is wrong, and the result can only be shown rigorously with $|B|$ in the denominator? Essentially the limit exist, but it is perhaps not that aligned with our intuition of conditional probability as the sequence approaches the limit.

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice as I first wrote the answer. I edited the post to fix this. Also, I added a short comment on why this limit 'is' the conditional expectation/probability of the event following the rigorous definition. I suggest reading [Durrett, R. (2019). Probability: theory and examples (Vol. 49). Cambridge university press.] if you are interested on a rigorous approach to probability theory, it helped me when I had similar doubts regarding conditional expectation.

Comment: Thanks! I am sure in the last paragraph you meant the conditional probability, not expectation, of $Y\in A$ given $X$ (or equivalently, $\mathbb{E}(1_A|X)$).